# triangular pyramid, trigonal pyramid offset-3d-Plane-Intersection By vbasolver

Tags: vba, sympy, offset, solver

triangular pyramid, trigonal pyramid offset-3d-Plane-Intersection By vbasolver

x=0.250 y=0.250 z=0.250　Inscribed sphere　Center

each plane offset 0.25 I challenge vba solver

why ALL-Row 0.250   0.250   0.250

I want ALL-Row 0.250   0.250   0.250

why 6row 8row error

The result is strange

Please tell me how to fix it.

```
Const x0 = 0
Const y0 = 0
Const z0 = 2
Const x1 = 0
Const y1 = 0
Const z1 = 0
Const x2 = 1
Const y2 = 0
Const z2 = 0
Const x3 = 0
Const y3 = 1
Const z3 = 0
Const r0 = 0.25
Const r1 = 0.25
Const r2 = 0.25
Const r3 = 0.25
Function myR1C1toA1(i, j)
    myR1C1toA1 = Application.ConvertFormula("R" & i & "C" & j, xlR1C1, xlA1)
End Function
Function myPlane(Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz)
   a = (By - Ay) * (Cz - Az) - (Cy - Ay) * (Bz - Az)
   b = (Bz - Az) * (Cx - Ax) - (Cz - Az) * (Bx - Ax)
   c = (Bx - Ax) * (Cy - Ay) - (Cx - Ax) * (By - Ay)
   d = -(a * Ax + b * Ay + c * Az)
   myPlane = Array(a, b, c, d)
End Function
Function myOffset3PlaneIntersection(irow, x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, r1, r2, r3)
    Dim v1 As Variant
    Dim v2 As Variant
    Dim v3 As Variant
'
    v1 = myPlane(x0, y0, z0, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3)
    v2 = myPlane(x0, y0, z0, x3, y3, z3, x1, y1, z1)
    v3 = myPlane(x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)
'
    my1 = "(Abs(" & v1(0) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(irow, 1) & "+ " & v1(1) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(irow, 2) & "+ " & v1(2) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(irow, 3) & "+ " & v1(3) & ") / Sqrt(" & v1(0) & " ^ 2 + " & v1(1) & " ^ 2 +" & v1(2) & " ^ 2) - " & myR1C1toA1(irow, 1) & ")"
    my2 = "(Abs(" & v2(0) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(irow, 1) & "+ " & v2(1) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(irow, 2) & "+ " & v2(2) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(irow, 3) & "+ " & v2(3) & ") / Sqrt(" & v2(0) & " ^ 2 + " & v2(1) & " ^ 2 +" & v2(2) & " ^ 2) - " & myR1C1toA1(irow, 2) & ")"
    my3 = "(Abs(" & v3(0) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(irow, 1) & "+ " & v3(1) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(irow, 2) & "+ " & v3(2) & " * " & myR1C1toA1(irow, 3) & "+ " & v3(3) & ") / Sqrt(" & v3(0) & " ^ 2 + " & v3(1) & " ^ 2 +" & v3(2) & " ^ 2) - " & myR1C1toA1(irow, 3) & ")"
    Range(myR1C1toA1(irow, 5)).Formula = "=" & my1 & "^ 2 +" & my2 & "^ 2 +" & my3 & "^ 2"
'
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    SolverReset
    SolverOk setCell:=ws.Range(myR1C1toA1(irow, 5)), _
                   MaxMinVal:=3, _
                   ByChange:=ws.Range(myR1C1toA1(irow, 1) & ":" & myR1C1toA1(irow, 3)), _
                   EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
     SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
End Function
Sub myFormat()
    Columns("A:E").Select
    Selection.NumberFormatLocal = "0.000_ "
    Range("A5").Select
End Sub
Sub aaa_Main()
    Dim myXYZ As Variant
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
MsgBox "Solver Start"
    Cells(1, 1) = x0
    Cells(1, 2) = y0
    Cells(1, 3) = z0
    Cells(2, 1) = x1
    Cells(2, 2) = y1
    Cells(2, 3) = z1
    Cells(3, 1) = x2
    Cells(3, 2) = y2
    Cells(3, 3) = z2
    Cells(4, 1) = x3
    Cells(4, 2) = y3
    Cells(4, 3) = z3
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    irow = 5
    Cells(irow + 0, 4) = r0
    Cells(irow + 1, 4) = r1
    Cells(irow + 2, 4) = r2
    Cells(irow + 3, 4) = r3
    myXYZ = myOffset3PlaneIntersection(irow + 0, x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, r1, r2, r3)
    myXYZ = myOffset3PlaneIntersection(irow + 1, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x0, y0, z0, r2, r3, r0)
    myXYZ = myOffset3PlaneIntersection(irow + 2, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, r3, r0, r1)
    myXYZ = myOffset3PlaneIntersection(irow + 3, x3, y3, z3, x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, r0, r1, r2)
   myFormat
End Sub

'1 0.000   0.000   2.000
'2 0.000   0.000   0.000
'3 1.000   0.000   0.000
'4 0.000   1.000   0.000
'5 0.250   0.250   0.250   0.250   0.000
'6 0.000   0.000   0.000   0.250   0.000   ???? I want 0.250   0.250   0.250
'7 0.250   0.250   0.250   0.250   0.000
'8 0.102   0.339   0.102   0.250   0.000   ???? I want 0.250   0.250   0.250
```

(2021-11-15)I try sympy

```
from sympy import *
def myVol(PTO,PTA,PTB,PTC):
    return Matrix([[PTA.x-PTO.x, PTA.y-PTO.y, PTA.z-PTO.z], [PTB.x-PTO.x, PTB.y-PTO.y, PTB.z-PTO.z], [PTC.x-PTO.x, PTC.y-PTO.y, PTC.z-PTO.z]]).det()/6
def myUnitVector(myPoint3D):
    myL=myPoint3D.distance((0, 0))
    return Point3D(myPoint3D.x/myL,myPoint3D.y/myL,myPoint3D.z/myL)
def myHtoP(myHairetu):
    return Point3D(myHairetu[0],myHairetu[1],myHairetu[2])
def my3PLaneIntersection(PTO,PTA,PTB,PTC,RA,RB,RC):
    vA =myUnitVector(myHtoP(Plane(PTO, PTB, PTC).normal_vector))
    PLA=Plane(PTO + RA * vA, normal_vector=vA)
    vB =myUnitVector(myHtoP(Plane(PTO, PTC, PTA).normal_vector))
    PLB=Plane(PTO + RB * vB, normal_vector=vB)
    vC =myUnitVector(myHtoP(Plane(PTO, PTA, PTB).normal_vector))
    PLC=Plane(PTO + RC * vC, normal_vector=vC)
    return PLC.intersection(PLB.intersection(PLA)[0])
PTO,PTA,PTB,PTC=Point3D(0,0,0),Point3D(1,0,0),Point3D(0,1,0),Point3D(0,0,2)
print("#",myVol(PTO,PTA,PTB,PTC))
myRO,myRA,myRB,myRC=0,0,0,0
print("#",myVol(
my3PLaneIntersection(PTO,PTA,PTB,PTC,myRO,myRO,myRO)[0],
my3PLaneIntersection(PTA,PTC,PTB,PTO,myRA,myRA,myRA)[0],
my3PLaneIntersection(PTB,PTC,PTO,PTA,myRB,myRB,myRB)[0],
my3PLaneIntersection(PTC,PTB,PTA,PTO,myRC,myRC,myRC)[0]))
myRO,myRA,myRB,myRC=1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4
print("#",myVol(
my3PLaneIntersection(PTO,PTA,PTB,PTC,myRO,myRO,myRO)[0],
my3PLaneIntersection(PTA,PTC,PTB,PTO,myRA,myRA,myRA)[0],
my3PLaneIntersection(PTB,PTC,PTO,PTA,myRB,myRB,myRB)[0],
my3PLaneIntersection(PTC,PTB,PTA,PTO,myRC,myRC,myRC)[0]))
myRO,myRA,myRB,myRC=-1/4,-1/4,-1/4,-1/4
print("#",myVol(
my3PLaneIntersection(PTO,PTA,PTB,PTC,myRO,myRO,myRO)[0],
my3PLaneIntersection(PTA,PTC,PTB,PTO,myRA,myRA,myRA)[0],
my3PLaneIntersection(PTB,PTC,PTO,PTA,myRB,myRB,myRB)[0],
my3PLaneIntersection(PTC,PTB,PTA,PTO,myRC,myRC,myRC)[0]))
# 1/3
# 1/3
# 0
# 8/3
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive and clear with defining the problem. Take your time and format the post to clearly lay out the objective, issue and your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check

```
from sympy import *
var('m')
def myUnitVector(myPoint3D):
    myL=myPoint3D.distance((0, 0))
    return Point3D(myPoint3D.x/myL,myPoint3D.y/myL,myPoint3D.z/myL)
def myHtoP(myHairetu):
    return Point3D(myHairetu[0],myHairetu[1],myHairetu[2])
def my3PLaneIntersection(PTO,PTA,PTB,PTC,RA,RB,RC):
    vA =myUnitVector(myHtoP(Plane(PTO, PTB, PTC).normal_vector))
    PLA=Plane(PTO + RA * vA, normal_vector=vA)
    vB =myUnitVector(myHtoP(Plane(PTO, PTC, PTA).normal_vector))
    PLB=Plane(PTO + RB * vB, normal_vector=vB)
    vC =myUnitVector(myHtoP(Plane(PTO, PTA, PTB).normal_vector))
    PLC=Plane(PTO + RC * vC, normal_vector=vC)
    return PLC.intersection(PLB.intersection(PLA)[0])
def myProjection(PTO,PTA,PTC,PTOO):
    v = myUnitVector(myHtoP(Plane(PTO, PTA, PTC).normal_vector))
    return solve(PTOO - Plane(PTO, PTA, PTC).projection(PTOO) - m * v, m)[m] * (-1)
PTO,PTA,PTB,PTC=Point3D(0,0,0),Point3D(1,0,0),Point3D(0,1,0),Point3D(0,0,2)
myRO,myRA,myRB,myRC=-1/4,-1/4,-1/4,-1/4
PTOO= my3PLaneIntersection(PTO, PTA,PTB,PTC,myRO,myRO,myRO)[0]
PTAA= my3PLaneIntersection(PTA, PTC,PTB,PTO,myRA,myRA,myRA)[0]
PTBB= my3PLaneIntersection(PTB, PTC,PTO,PTA,myRB,myRB,myRB)[0]
PTCC= my3PLaneIntersection(PTC, PTB,PTA,PTO,myRC,myRC,myRC)[0]
print("#",PTOO,"\n#",PTAA,"\n#",PTBB,"\n#",PTCC,)
print("#",myProjection(PTO,PTB,PTA,PTOO),
          myProjection(PTO,PTA,PTC,PTOO),
          myProjection(PTO,PTC,PTB,PTOO))
print("#",myProjection(PTA,PTO,PTB,PTAA),
          myProjection(PTA,PTC,PTO,PTAA),
          myProjection(PTA,PTB,PTC,PTAA))
print("#",myProjection(PTB,PTA,PTO,PTBB),
          myProjection(PTB,PTO,PTC,PTBB),
          myProjection(PTB,PTC,PTA,PTBB))
print("#",myProjection(PTC,PTO,PTA,PTCC),
          myProjection(PTC,PTB,PTO,PTCC),
          myProjection(PTC,PTA,PTB,PTCC))
# Point3D(-1/4, -1/4, -1/4) 
# Point3D(7/4, -1/4, -1/4) 
# Point3D(-1/4, 7/4, -1/4) 
# Point3D(-1/4, -1/4, 15/4)
# -1/4 -1/4 -1/4
# -1/4 -1/4 -1/4
# -1/4 -1/4 -1/4
# -1/4 -1/4 -1/4
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).